# Vf Page in Pagelayout

Tags: page-layout

Is there any way to find the presence of vf page in page layout without using any migration tool ? 
I need to prepare a document which must have the list of vf pages that are in page layout of different objects . Can we use soql or sosl to achieve this functionality . Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to be done through Apex code using MetadataService class (https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls).

First of all, you will need to retrieve all layouts names:

```
List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery> queries = new List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery>();
MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery queryLayouts = new MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery();
queryLayouts.type_x = 'Layout';
queries.add(queryLayouts);
MetadataService.FileProperties[] fileProperties = helper.getService().listMetadata(queries, 42);
```

After that, collect all layouts names and query actual layouts with their content.

```
helper.getService().readMetadata('Layout', batch).getRecords();
```

Then iterate through requested layouts and run through **customConsoleComponents**. VF pages should be listed there. The documentation will help you to retrieve pages names: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_layouts.htm